# Hello World blank screen on startup

Tags: android

I started working with android studio and was following a book making a hello world app. As soon as I finish first declaring the project and running gradle it's supposed to have a header with hello world at the top like this

[image]

But instead I get

this

[image]

I haven't touched any of the code. But here's the activity_quiz.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".QuizActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help?

Comment: it would help if you show the onCreate method in it's entirety.

Comment: So I'm retarded, used the avd and it works, but is there any way I can instantly see changes I make to the design without running the app everytime?

Comment: So I guess a better question would be is, why is the preview always blank??

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that it's  your constraints on the textview.  Avoid using "left" and "right", instead use "start" and "end".  Using left and right is not recommend.  ConstraintLayout can be a bit of a learning curve, but once you master it, it's much better for design than anything else.